# modal verbs at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

> Must not have prior convictions for the commission of crimes in the economic sphere: corruption, money laundering etc. Must not be in the sanctions lists.

I think this use of 'must' is incorrect. I would appreciate your explaination about the possibility/impossibility of using this verb at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. These are not sentences; they look like a list of job requirements.

Answer (score 2):

These constructions  are fine. (Although some people might argue that they're not complete sentences.)  In these examples the construction is  used to present requirements for some type of position, so the implied subject is *the candidate*. And the understood thought is

> (The candidate)
>   1 must not this...
>   2 must not that...
>   3 must demonstrate this ability...
>   Etc